# Child ignore parents padding

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a portfolio item with an image, it is places within a section that has padding left and right. The problem is that I need the image to be to the edges and ignore section padding. I tried adding negative margin and some tricks I found on stackoverflow with padding but it didn't work, it just centered the image with more padding/margin.

HTML:

```
<section id="portfolio">

        <!-- Section title -->
        <h2 class="section-title">Portfolio</h2>
        <!-- Section description -->
        <p class="section-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

        <!-- Grid layout -->
        <ul class="portfolio-grid">
            <!-- Item -->
            <li class="portfolio-grid-item">
                <!-- Item link -->
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-grid-item-link">
                    <!-- Item image -->
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" alt="Image">
                    <!-- Item overlay -->
                    <span class="portfolio-grid-item-overlay"></span>
                    <!-- Item name -->
                    <span class="portfolio-grid-item-name">Item name</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </section>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6qczx2h/)

Comment: try to set the image position:absolute; top:0;

Comment: So I would get a lot of images stacked on top of each other?

Comment: if you want to ignore the section padding then put it to '0'

Comment: I need the padding on the rest of the section except the image grid.

Comment: you can achieve what you want ( I hope) by adding position : absolute and margin-left: -30px  to the .portfolio-grid.

Comment: It works, thank you, but why 30px? You can put your answer so I can checkmark it if you want.

Comment: @Leon Laci I updated my answer, check it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `<body>` has margins on all browsers. So all you need to do is shave them off:

```
body{
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
}
```

If you want a bit of padding-left on your text, write to specific elements where you want padding. Don't write to `<section>` , as it adds padding to all elements you have inside there!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9mg03wa5/2/

Comment: I know I am a little late but I tried testing it in the actual project and the portfolio-grid class just goes above the content that is below it.

Comment: @Leon Laci mind if you reproduce your unexpected result into a fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9mg03wa5/ As you can see the paragraph elements just sing below the portfolio-grid because it is an absolute element.

Comment: @Leon Laci yup, that was the problem. Remove position:absolute from him to solve that problem.  Write in CSS body { padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; }. In addition, if you want a bit of padding-left on your text, write to specific elements where you want padding. Don't write to <section> , as it adds padding to all you have inside there.

Comment: Can you change the answer so other people won't be confused by using absolute positioning?